# Exit a loop if another thread enter in the

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I've a multi-threading issue.

I've a method that is called to make refresh on several items.

In this method, I iterate on a list of items and refresh one of it's property.

The list has a lot of elements and we have to do some math to compute it's property.

The current code of this operation look like this:

```
public void AddItemsWithLayoutRefresh(IEnumerable<MyItem> items){
    _control.Invoke(()=>{
        AddItems(items);
        for(int i =0;i<_guiItems.Count;i++){
            //The goal is to have a condition here to "break" the loop and let the next call to RefreshLayout proceed
            _guiItems[i].Propriety = ComputePropriety(_guiItems[i]);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that I may have 4 call, which are currently just blocking on the `Invoke`.
I've to finish the "AddItems" methods, but concerning everything that is in the "for" loop, I can abort this without any issue if I know that it will be executed just after.

But how to do this in a thread-safe way?

If I put a `private bool _isNewRefreshHere;`, set to true before entering the Invoke, then checking in the `Invoke`, I've no warranty that there is not already two call that have reach the Invoke BEFORE I check it in the for loop.

So how can I `break` when being in my loop when a new call is made to my method?

**Solution**
Based on Andrej Mohar's answer, I did the following:

```
private long m_refreshQueryCount;
public void AddItemsWithLayoutRefresh(IEnumerable<MyItem> items){
    Interlocked.Increment(ref m_refreshQueryCount);
    _control.Invoke(()=>{
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_refreshQueryCount);
        AddItems(items);
        for(int i =0;i<_guiItems.Count;i++){
            if (Interlocked.Read(ref m_refreshQueryCount) > 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            _guiItems[i].Propriety = ComputePropriety(_guiItems[i]);
        }
    });
}
```

Which seems to work very nicely

Comment: Why don't you use a `lock`?

Comment: Lock where? The Invoke already ensure that there is only one running process. What I want is to stop the current Invoke if a new Invoke is made

Comment: By the way, you are you adding multiple items **with** layout refresh? It provides nothing but performance reduction. What's wrong with `Suspend/Resume` layout?

Comment: @AgentFire The method is maybe not named very well, but in the real code, we have to call explicitely a method of our library to update the GUI according of what changes have been made.

Comment: @J4N so why don't you suspend the layout, add the items, and then resume the layout?

Comment: I already suspend the layout. The operation that takes a lot of CPU is computing the property of each items, not updating the layout

Comment: @J4N alright, why then do you spending CPU time on computing **on GUI thread**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd try to make a thread-safe waiting counter. You can use [Interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Interlocked_methods.aspx) methods like Increment and Decrement. What these basically do is they increment the value as an atomic operation, which is considered to be thread-safe. So you increase the variable before the Invoke call. This will allow you to know how many threads are in the waiting queue. You decrement the variable after the for loop finishes and before the ending of the Invoke block. You can then check inside the for statement for the number of waiting threads and break the for if the number is greater than 1. This way you should know exactly how many threads are in the execution chain.

Comment: This is actually why the [`Semaphore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) was created for.

Comment: @Andrej Mohar : Thank you, it's what I'm looking for! I was starting the implementation of this kind of behavior myself, with a lock and an int!
AgendFire : I don't see a way to see the number of thread currently waiting on the semaphore? In my case, it's the thread that has the semaphore that should check if other thread are waiting.

Comment: @AgentFire: Are you sure? Hm, I might have understood the semaphores wrong. I thought the semaphores watch how many threads can be running in the protected part of the code. I was thinking more of making a check part of the code which would be able to display the number of threads waiting and according to that number break the execution as needed.

Comment: I used your solution to build my final solution. I edited my question to add the final result. Thank you!

Comment: No problems, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in the following way:

```
private readonly object _refresherLock = new object();
private bool _isNewRefreshHere = false;
private AutoResetEvent _refresher = new AutoResetEvent(true);

public void AddItemsWithLayoutRefresh(IEnumerable<MyItem> items)
{
    lock (_refresherLock)
    {
         if (_isNewRefreshHere)
         {
             return;
         }

         _isNewRefreshHere = true;
    }

    _refresher.WaitOne();
    _isNewRefreshHere = false;

    _control.Invoke(() =>
    {
        AddItems(items);

        for (int i = 0; i < _guiItems.Count && !_isNewRefreshHere; i++)
        {
            _guiItems[i].Propriety = ComputePropriety(_guiItems[i]);
        }

        _refresher.Set();
    });
}
```

That is:

- You can always cancel the current updation with a new one.
- You cannot queue up more than one updation at a time.
- You are guaranteed to have no cross-threading conflicts.
- You should test that code since I did not. :)

Comment: It may be a good idea, but I need to not return of my method until the refresh is correctly done.

Comment: @J4N What do you mean?

Comment: if I've 3 thread, A, B and C, A will enter, B and C comes very quickly, B win and set `_isNewRefreshHere`to true, C comes, see that `_isNewRefreshHere` is set to true and return, but the layout hasn't been refreshed yet. So the caller will think that everything has been correctly refreshed even if it's not the case

Comment: @J4N that is very, **very** weird workflow, but it that case I would recomment you to add `_refresher.WaitOne(); _refresher.Set();` after the `return` line...